# parMapN Missing Method from Ciris.ConfigValue

Tags: scala, casting

I do not understand this error.  I know it is telling that ConfigValue does not have a method defined called parMapN.

value parMapN is not a member of (ciris.ConfigValue[ciris.Effect,Int], ciris.ConfigValue[ciris.Effect,String])
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value parMapN'?
).parMapN((port, host) => ServerConfig(Port(port), Host(host)))

```
package com.rusty.core.config

import cats.effect.kernel.Async
import ciris.{ConfigValue, env}
import com.rusty.core.domain.{Host, Port}
import cats.implicits._


final case class ServerConfig(
    port: Port,
    host: Host
)

object ServerConfig {
  def serverConfig[F[_]: Async]: ConfigValue[F, ServerConfig] = (
    env("PORT").as[Int].default(8080),
    env("HOST").default("localhost")
  ).parMapN((port, host) => ServerConfig(Port(port), Host(host)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `parMapN` requires an instance of `Parallel[F]`, which you can get from `Async`. To do that, add this:

```scala
import cats.effect.implicits._
```